How to manage text arrangement in Jetpack Compose
How can i arrange text in compose such a way that whether content is of 1 line or 2 line, the time text is always shown in the end just like whatsapp
here is example if short text:
lorem ipsum dolor 12:34 PM

here is example if that chat text is long so this will move date time to bellow:
lorem ipsum dolor....foobar
                    12:30PM

here is if the chat text wrapping:
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum tai bau    12:30 PM


I fix this with simple way, just add the dt both
Text: lorem ipsum dolor 12.45(but transparently)
Then make absolute dt time and put it where's we want

If you wish to cover scenario where text is multiple lines and width of last line + date is smaller than total width, in that case date should be at the same line with last line of text as
lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
lorem ipsum tai bau    12:30 PM


You should measure Text and check if it is multiple lines and width of last line + time is smaller than width of parent.
Measure how many lines Text has, width of last line, width of message and date Composables and width of parent. Then, using a Layout you can position text and date. You can check and copy paste source code from https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Flexible-Chat-Box
You can measure text inside onTextLayout callback of Text Composable or with a TextMeasurer
onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult ->
    // maxWidth of text constraint returns parent maxWidth - horizontal padding
    chatRowData.lineCount = textLayoutResult.lineCount
    chatRowData.lastLineWidth =
        textLayoutResult.getLineRight(chatRowData.lineCount - 1)
    chatRowData.textWidth = textLayoutResult.size.width
}

data class ChatRowData(
    var text: String = "",
    // Width of the text without padding
    var textWidth: Int = 0,
    var lastLineWidth: Float = 0f,
    var lineCount: Int = 0,
    var rowWidth: Int = 0,
    var rowHeight: Int = 0,
    var parentWidth: Int = 0,
    var measuredType: Int = 0,
) {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "ChatRowData text: $text, " +
                "lastLineWidth: $lastLineWidth, lineCount: $lineCount, " +
                "textWidth: ${textWidth}, rowWidth: $rowWidth, height: $rowHeight, " +
                "parentWidth: $parentWidth, measuredType: $measuredType"
    }
}

Calculate row width and height based on conditions mentioned above. This is actually only part that is essential. Since i used Layout need to pass Placeables as params but you can pass dimension of parent and children as pixels if you wish to construct your layout in another way.
private fun calculateChatWidthAndHeight(
    chatRowData: ChatRowData,
    message: Placeable,
    status: Placeable?,
) {

    if (status != null) {

        val lineCount = chatRowData.lineCount
        val lastLineWidth = chatRowData.lastLineWidth
        val parentWidth = chatRowData.parentWidth

        val padding = (message.measuredWidth - chatRowData.textWidth) / 2

        // Multiple lines and last line and status is longer than text size and right padding
        if (lineCount > 1 && lastLineWidth + status.measuredWidth >= chatRowData.textWidth + padding) {
            chatRowData.rowWidth = message.measuredWidth
            chatRowData.rowHeight = message.measuredHeight + status.measuredHeight
            chatRowData.measuredType = 0
        } else if (lineCount > 1 && lastLineWidth + status.measuredWidth < chatRowData.textWidth + padding) {
            // Multiple lines and last line and status is shorter than text size and right padding
            chatRowData.rowWidth = message.measuredWidth
            chatRowData.rowHeight = message.measuredHeight
            chatRowData.measuredType = 1
        } else if (lineCount == 1 && message.width + status.measuredWidth >= parentWidth) {
            chatRowData.rowWidth = message.measuredWidth
            chatRowData.rowHeight = message.measuredHeight + status.measuredHeight
            chatRowData.measuredType = 2
        } else {
            chatRowData.rowWidth = message.measuredWidth + status.measuredWidth
            chatRowData.rowHeight = message.measuredHeight
            chatRowData.measuredType = 3
        }
    } else {
        chatRowData.rowWidth = message.width
        chatRowData.rowHeight = message.height
    }
}

Inside Layout set dimensions place message and date according to this data
Layout(
    modifier = modifier,
    content = content
) { measurables: List<Measurable>, constraints: Constraints ->

    if (measurables.size != 2)
        throw IllegalArgumentException("There should be 2 components for this layout")
    
    val placeables: List<Placeable> = measurables.map { measurable ->
        // Measure each child maximum constraints since message can cover all of the available
        // space by parent
        measurable.measure(Constraints(0, constraints.maxWidth))
    }

    val message = placeables.first()
    val status = placeables.last()

    // calculate chat row dimensions are not  based on message and status positions
    if ((chatRowData.rowWidth == 0 || chatRowData.rowHeight == 0) || chatRowData.text != text) {
        // Constrain with max width instead of longest sibling
        // since this composable can be longest of siblings after calculation
        chatRowData.parentWidth = constraints.maxWidth
        calculateChatWidthAndHeight( chatRowData, message, status)
        // Parent width of this chat row is either result of width calculation
        // or quote or other sibling width if they are longer than calculated width.
        // minWidth of Constraint equals (text width + horizontal padding)
        chatRowData.parentWidth =
            chatRowData.rowWidth.coerceAtLeast(minimumValue = constraints.minWidth)
    }
    
    // Send measurement results if requested by Composable
    onMeasure?.invoke(chatRowData)

    layout(width = chatRowData.parentWidth, height = chatRowData.rowHeight) {
        
        message.placeRelative(0, 0)
        // set left of status relative to parent because other elements could result this row
        // to be long as longest composable
        status.placeRelative(
            chatRowData.parentWidth - status.width,
            chatRowData.rowHeight - status.height
        )
    }
}


You can create a Row to hold the message text and the time text. Inside the Row, you can use a Column to hold the message text.
Also, Modifier.weight(1f) to the Column that contains the message text. This ensures that the column takes up all available space, pushing the time text to the end of the row.
@Composable
fun ChatMessageLayout(message: String, time: String) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = message
            )
        }
        Text(
            text = time,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 8.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Bottom)
        )
    }
}


Update
After taking inspiration from the answer provided by @Thracian, you can achieve your requirement by checking whether text is singleline or multiline and then place time text approximately using Layout:
@Preview
@Composable
fun ChatMessageLayoutPreview() {
    ChatMessage("Hello".repeat(200), "12:00")
}

@Composable
fun ChatMessage(message: String, time: String) {
    Layout(
        content = {
            Text(text =message)
            Text(text = time)
        },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
    ) { measurables, constraints ->
        // Measure the message and time
        val messagePlaceable = measurables[0].measure(constraints)
        val timePlaceable = measurables[1].measure(constraints)

        // Check if the message fits in a single line
        val isSingleLine = messagePlaceable.width + timePlaceable.width <= constraints.maxWidth

        // Determine the layout width and height
        val width = constraints.maxWidth
        val height = if (isSingleLine) {
            maxOf(messagePlaceable.height, timePlaceable.height)
        } else {
            messagePlaceable.height + timePlaceable.height
        }

        layout(width, height) {
            if (isSingleLine) {
                // Place message and time side by side
                messagePlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                timePlaceable.placeRelative(width - timePlaceable.width, 0)
            } else {
                // Place message above and time below
                messagePlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
                timePlaceable.placeRelative(width - timePlaceable.width, messagePlaceable.height)
            }
        }
    }
}

Sample Output:


I think this is not going to work if the text is going across multiple lines. Then there will be a gap on each line across all lines.

Thank you for bringing this to my attention @BenjyTec. Will update my answer accordingly

There is more space actually we don't make the date time flow to next line
